# Doctrine2 cascade entity creation

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two entities User and UserProfile. UserProfile primaryKey value is not AUTO_INCREMENT, it is on-to-one relation using primary key value from User. When I create new User I have an error:

> Entity of type App\PublicBundle\Entity\User\UserProfile is missing an assigned ID for field 'user'. The identifier generation strategy for this entity requires the ID field to be populated before EntityManager#persist() is called. If you want automatically generated identifiers instead you need to adjust the metadata mapping accordingly.

**The question is** how can I save entity with the next database and entity structure:

**User DDL:**

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `intUserID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`intUserID`),
)
CREATE TABLE `user_profile` (
  `intUserID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`intUserID`),
  CONSTRAINT `user_profile_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`intUserID`) REFERENCES `user` (`intUserID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
```

**User Entity:**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="intUserID", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    protected $intuserid;

    /**
     * @var \App\PublicBundle\Entity\User\UserProfile
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="\App\PublicBundle\Entity\User\UserProfile",
     *      mappedBy="user",
     *      cascade={"persist", "remove"}
     * )
     */
    protected $profile;
}
```

**UserProfile Entity:**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="user_profile")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class UserProfile
{
    /**
     * @var \App\PublicBundle\Entity\User\User
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="\App\PublicBundle\Entity\User\User",
     *      inversedBy="profile"
     * )
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="intUserID", referencedColumnName="intUserID")
     * })
     */
    protected $user;
}
```

**Registration action**

```
private function registration(Request $request, $tpl)
{
    $user = new User();
    $form = $this->$form($user, 'Create');
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ('POST' === $request->getMethod())
    {
        if ($form->isValid())
        {
            $em->getConnection()->beginTransaction();

            try
            {
                $em = $this->getManager();
                $em->persist($user);
                $em->flush();

                $this->sendSuccessEmail($user);
                $em->getConnection()->commit();
            }
            catch (\Exception $e)
            {
                $em->getConnection()->rollback();
                throw $e;
            }

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('app_profile'));
        }
    }

    return $this->render($tpl, array(
        'entity' => $user,
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ));
}
```

Comment: Trying to keep two primary keys in sync is usually more trouble than it's worth.  Especially when using an Object Relation Manager such as Doctrine 2.  Just go with the flow and give your UserProfile it's own database id.  Or use an embedded value object.

Comment: Yes, I thought about that, but I suppose that another more correct way is exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct way, it's set to null profile before persist and flush and call persist and flush again:

**Registration action**

```
private function registration(Request $request, $tpl)
{
    $user = new User();
    $form = $this->$form($user, 'Create');
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ('POST' === $request->getMethod())
    {
        if ($form->isValid())
        {
            $em->getConnection()->beginTransaction();

            try
            {
                $user->setProfile(null);

                $em = $this->getManager();
                $em->persist($user);
                $em->flush();

                $user->setProfile(new UserProfile);
                $user->getProfile()->setUser($user);

                $em = $this->getManager();
                $em->persist($user);
                $em->flush();

                $this->sendSuccessEmail($user);
                $em->getConnection()->commit();
            }
            catch (\Exception $e)
            {
                $em->getConnection()->rollback();
                throw $e;
            }

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('app_profile'));
        }
    }

    return $this->render($tpl, array(
        'entity' => $user,
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ));
}
```